# Making A Better Contact List Display with Javascript (CodeCademy)

Tags: javascript

I'm having a hard time figuring out ways to make the output display in an organised manner. How could I change the output to make it look according to the picture?

- [Ugly Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PLEX.png)
- [Nice Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMwWz.png)

**MY CODE**

```
var friends = {};

friends.bill = {
   firstName: "Bill",
   lastName: "Wang", 
   number: "0000000001",
   nationality: "Australian",
   address: ['Street','Microsoft','California','SL','98052']
};

friends.steve = {
   firstName: "Steve",
   lastName: "Wozniak",
   number: "0021221312",
   nationality: "American",
   address: ['Street','Apple','California','SL','98052']
};


var list = function(obj){

    for(var check in obj){
    console.log(check);      
    }
};

var search = function(name){

    for(var prop in friends){
        if(friends[prop].firstName === name) {
            console.log(friends[prop]);
            return friends[prop];
        }
    }
};

list(friends);
search("Bill");
```

Comment: instead of logging the object as is, create a custom function that will print it pretty

Comment: console.log() isn't your stuff. You need something of yours to do that in your way.

Comment: Hi Banana, do I need to specify each object key and value into the new function? I can't picture what it is like. Could you provide a brief example? Thanks!!

Comment: Ashad, so I'll need to omit console.log() and use a function instead?

Comment: `console.log("first name: "+ myFriend.Fname); console.log("last name: "+ myFriend.Lname)` like this

Comment: sure no problem :) check out my answer, there is a neater way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

logging an object into the console directly, will log it according to the browser's built in mechanism. every browser will output objects in its own way, so if you want it to look pretty you need to create a custom function where you will print everything according to your needs.

you could create a class named "Friend" with an extension method `PrintFriend()` where you would output all the relevant information, and instantiate your friends from it:

```js
var friends = {};
//this is our class declaration
var Friend = function (firstName, lastName, number, nationality, address) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.number = number;
    this.nationality = nationality;
    this.address = address;
};
//a prototype function that will be available to all objects of 
//class 'Friend'
Friend.prototype.PrintFriend = function () {
    console.log("First Name: " + this.firstName);
    console.log("Last Name: " + this.lastName);
    console.log("Number: " + this.number);
    console.log("Address: " + this.address.join().replace(/,/g," "));

document.body.innerHTML+="First Name: " + this.firstName+"<br/>";
document.body.innerHTML+="Last Name: " + this.lastName+"<br/>";
document.body.innerHTML+="Number: " + this.number+"<br/>";
document.body.innerHTML+="Address: " + this.address.join().replace(/,/g," ")+"<br/>";
};
//we add an object named 'bill' to the friends array, the object will
//be instantiated from the Friend class
friends["bill"] = new Friend(
    "Bill",
    "Wang",
    "0000000001",
    "Australian", ['Street', 'Microsoft', 'California', 'SL', '98052']);
//same with steve
friends["steve"] = new Friend(
    "Steve",
    "Wozniak",
    "0021221312",
    "American", ['Street', 'Apple', 'California', 'SL', '98052']);


var list = function (obj) {
    for (var check in obj) {
        console.log(check);
    }
};
//we call the custom function print friend here
var search = function (name) {

    for (var prop in friends) {
        if (friends[prop].firstName === name) {
            friends[prop].PrintFriend();
            return friends[prop];
        }
    }
};

list(friends);
search("Bill");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write a function rather than using console.log directly.
Something like:

```
var logFriend = function(friend){
    console.log("First Name: " + friend. firstName);
    console.log("Last Name: " + friend. lastName);
    console.log("Number: (" + friend.number.substring(0, 2) + ") " + friend.number.substring(3, 9));
}
```